# Backbone PUT requests and Laravel

Tags: php, api, rest, backbone.js, laravel

I am working with a Backbone front end and a Laravel REST api backend, I am seeing some strange behaviour when sending a a PUT request and then trying to read that data at the API end.

If I do the following,

`Input::all()` this returns a NULL array, however if I explicitly state which attribute I want from the Input then that works fine i.e `Input::get('name')` returns "Jon Doe" I have tried to find some resources on this problem, 2 solutions I have found are,

add `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />` to my forms that are used for editing a model, this does not seem to work, the second is change the content-type of the requests from Backbone from `application/json` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` but I cannot figure how to do this.

What is simplest way of getting the data from a PUT request - ideally I do not want to use `Backbone.emulateHTTP` as I don't fully understand how I would differentiate between a POST, for an edit, save and delete.

==============UPDATE==============

Strangely I have just removed all my code for the method I am working with, and `Input::all()` now returns the form data submitted, so confused!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Laravel4 working with Backbone, you should create a REST interface with the back end, implementing Resourceful controllers that use the RESTful methods as prescribed by Laravel.

In the front end, you should create Backbone models to store the state of the data.
A PUT request occurs when you define an id on a Backbone model before you persist it to the server.

Therefore I would first manage all front end application data with your Backbone models, persisting the data by using Backbone 'save' on the model.

Whether you use Input::all() or Input::get('name') is irrelevant and depends on your requirement. Usually, the controller only serves as a channel through which you send your parameters towards your repository/model. I tend to use Input::all() and manage my conditions (individual parameters) in either the repository or the model.